# Is functional calculus continuous on elements of the algebra.

Tags: continuity, c-star-algebras, functional-calculus

Suppose $A$ is a C*-algebra, $a$ is a hermitian  element of $A$. For each continous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{C}$, we say $f$ is *continuous on $A$* if for every sequence $\{a_\lambda\}$ of positive elements in  $A$ converging to $a$, $f(a_\lambda)\to f(a)$.

The assertion "every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous on $A$" seems wrong, but I want to know the case for the square root function $x\to \sqrt{x}$. In fact, I want to know  if $A\to A, a\mapsto  |a|$ is continuous.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion holds in general. The key fact is that if $a_\lambda$ is close enough to $a$, so is its norm. Thus we may assume that all spectra are contained in a fixed interval $[0,r]$.

Then we may approximate $f$ uniformly: given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a polynomial $p$ with $\|f-p\|<\varepsilon$. Then
\begin{align}
\|f(a_\lambda)-f(a)\|&\leq 
\|f(a_\lambda)-p(a_\lambda)\|+\|p(a_\lambda)-p(a)\|+\|p(a)-f(a)\|\\ \ \\
&\leq \varepsilon+ \|p(a_\lambda)-p(a)\|\\ \ \\
&\leq 2 \varepsilon +\|p(a_\lambda)-p(a)\|.
\end{align}
With $p$ fixed, we obtain 
$$
\limsup\|f(a_\lambda)-f(a)\|\leq 2\varepsilon. 
$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary and $r$ was fixed, the limsup is zero, and so the limit exists and is zero:
$$
\lim_\lambda \|f(a_\lambda)-f(a)\|=0. 
$$

Comment: Thx! ($\|p(a)-f(a)\|\leq \|p-f\|\leq \varepsilon$ with no  coefficient $\|a\|$ I think.)

Comment: Yes, you are right.